Woman likes married man who kindly turns her down
I'm trying to identify the source of this scene in a movie or TV show:

This was a TV show or movie from the 1990s or 2000s
A younger woman is attracted to an older, married man who is well-dressed and good-looking, kind of like Pierce Brosnan
He might have been of some sort of Hispanic or Latino descent, but I'm not
sure
They might have worked together, but I'm not sure
The two of them are talking -- I think it's while having a meal at
a restaurant, but I'm not sure
He kindly tells her that they cannot have a relationship, even though
he likes her very much (I was surprised as movies/TV stories usually don't show characters not having an affair) 
She is surprised and frustrated, but accepting


Though I'm sure you would've added more details by now if you remembered them, I'm afraid this might not be enough... You're describing a very generic scene and this could be many, many things.

I wish I could come up with more. I don't think I saw the whole movie - just a portion. If it helps, I think the man was maybe 45 and a very well-bred, well-manicured, dignified type of handsome, kind of like a Pierce Brosnan look. The woman was attractive, brunette, maybe 25. He is extremely polite when he turns down her offer of an affair. She is surprised by his declining, and a little miffed, but not furious -- more disappointed.

Do you remember the speaking language, country, if it was color or black and white? What exactly of this scene impressed you so much because, as @Walt said, it seems like generic scene from any kind of movie. If you have/remember any additional info, please add them to the question body, so we don't go mining details through comments.

@Advicer, I added some more info to question body

Could be "Mr. Holland's Opus".
Mr. Holland is a music teacher in a high school, and one year when doing the school revue, he has an ingenue with an incredible voice. During the rehearsals and other musical events, she becomes attracted to him, and to some extent vice versa. When she wants to go to New York to pursue a vocal career, she asks him to come with. Slightly later he refuses her, but gives her the number of an old band mate to look after her when she arrives. She is sad, but accepting of his decision.

Thank you, but it was a different movie... the man was not Richard Dreyfuss.
